# Does my mesh have a good poly count for a game?

Tags: topology

I'm a beginner 3d designer and I'm making a model, but I want to know if my model has a good poly count for a game. (Image included) If anyone can help thanks.

[image: screen shot of mesh wireframe]

Comment: Also, if it isn't good what can I do?

Comment: Hello and welcome. This site works best for focused questions and answers and is not 
meant for opinions or open ended discussions. You can use the forums 
at https://blenderartists.org/, there are sections for focused 
critique and work in progress. To understand how to make better use of 
this site please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center 
section, particularly [How do I ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?]https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Flagged as opinion based. Here's an opinion: for spheres and cylinders it has way too many triangles, especially for a video game. But I could imagine scenarios that would justify the amount...

Comment: See https://polycount.com/discussion/141061/polycounts-in-next-gen-games-thread for recent-ish stuff in AAA titles (which will be more optimized than most indy things.)  The short answer: no, your meshes have way too many polygons for what they are for use in a game.  By at least sixteen-fold.  The long answer: This is the wrong thing to measure.  You need to know *scene* poly counts; you need to know armature deformed poly counts per scene.  Talk to your coder to make a test to see what you can afford in your engine.  If you are the coder, make your own test.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of question is usually closed as "opinion based" because a yes or no answer is a matter of opinion, but it's a good opportunity to describe what "too many polygons" means and that's something new modelers can benefit from.

Your question can't be answered in a vacuum.  To know how many polygons a model can be allowed, we need to know what it is going to be used for.  Crudely put, there are three classes of game assets, and the first two both require *low* polygon counts.  The third class might allow a high polygon count, but even that depends.

The first kind of asset is not important.  It might be a building in the distance, or a rock close up that's among a pile of rocks.  Such assets should be low polygon assets, because they're simply not going to get notices.

The second kind of asset is more important, but should still have a low polygon count.  These are props that might be noticed, like a sword on a rack, but that aren't going to be seen very close up or in great detail.

The final kind of asset is often called a *hero* asset.  It might be the main character, or the object of the quest.  It will receive a lot of attention in the came, be seen close up, and its detail will be important.

But that leaves us with the question of what are 'low' and 'high' polygon counts.  That too depends and can't be answered in a vacuum.

First, there's how powerful the machine's graphics are that the game will run on.  A low polygon count on a high end game console might well be a high polygon count on a smartphone.

Second, there's the overall artistic style of the game.  A game that's meant to be nearly photorealistic will demand a much higher polygon count of each asset than a game that's deliberately styled for a low-polygon world.

So, as you can see, there's no one-size-fits-all answer, but there is a good rule that many asset developers follow:

*An asset should have as many polygons as is necessary for it to fit the artistic style of the game its meant for and the role it has in that game but no more than that.*

That said, there's another aspect, and it applies to your model in particular: sometimes you can get the appearance you want by using fewer polygons but other techniques to create the impression of detail.

In your case, you have spheres and hemispheres that have far higher polygon counts than needed to give the impression of a smooth round object, even in a hero asset.  Reduce the polygon count and rely on shading techniques to give you the smoothness.

Also related, is the need to fake detail by using shaders, doing things like creating bump maps that give the appearance of detail but without the high polygon count.